# runOnUi slows down the app and make it forced close

Tags: java, android

i am generating a random string for infinite time and setting it to a EditText.
when i was not using runOnUi app was working on newer devices which have high capability. but it crashes on older model when i start the thread and gave error(called from wrong thread exception)

Then i used runOnUi but it makes the super slow and force close it.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       while (true) {
                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   try {
                                       tryPass.setText(getAlphaNumericString());
                                       Thread.sleep(2000);
                                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }


                               }
                           });
                       }
                   }
               });
               thread.start();
```

Comment: You don't need a new Thread. Also your `Thread.sleep` is probably doing something that you have not in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to block UI thread by calling `Thread.sleep(2000);` on UI thread.

Try this way:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tryPass.setText(getAlphaNumericString());
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: it worked thanks.i was trying it from yesterday then finally asked. can you please explain why try catch was causing this problem.

Comment: you were calling `Thread.sleep(2000);` on UI thread, but by moving **sleep** outside the UI block, sleep will just delay the next iteration instead of blocking ui thread. 
If this solution solved your problem, please approve my answer.